# No selected items shown with selectMultipleSideBySide and MM_match_fields in TYPO3 TCA

Tags: typo3, backend

This is my TCA:

```
tx_csblog_tags' => [
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:cs_blog/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_csblog_domain_model_post.tags',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_csblog_domain_model_tag',
            'foreign_table_where' => ' ORDER BY tx_csblog_domain_model_tag.title ASC',
            'MM' => 'tx_csblog_post_tag_mm',
            'MM_match_fields' => [
                'tablenames' => 'pages',
                'fieldname' => 'tx_csblog_tags'
            ],
            'nultiple' => 0,
            'size' => 10,
            'autoSizeMax' => 30,
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 9999,
```

The selected items are stored correct in the database table tx_csblog_post_tag_mm, e.g.

```
uid_local uid_foreign sorting sorting_foreign tablenames fieldname
143      18       1       0               pages  tx_csblog_tags
```

If I save the record, the selected items will be stored in the database this way, but not shown again as selected. So if I save again, the relations are gone.

Did I miss something or is it not possible to use MM_match_fields like this?

Comment: I can see a typo `'nultiple'`. Though I believe `multiple` its false by default anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I leave the "tablenames" it works.